# How to get an element on the page by attribute

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I use ling to xml to retrieve a specific child element given its parent element attribute?

For example, if I have the following extract from an xml document, I would like to alter the value of TextAlign. There may be several TextBox objects and thus a hardcoded query is not useful:

```
  <Textbox Name="pageHeaderReportTitle">
    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
    <Height>1cm</Height>
    <Left>45pt</Left>
    <Style>
      <BackgroundColor>#4F81BD</BackgroundColor>
      <Color>White</Color>
      <FontSize>14pt</FontSize>
      <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
      <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
      <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
    </Style>
    <Top>90pt</Top>
    <Value>=iif(len("") &gt; 0 ,iif(len("Employees") &gt; 0,"Employees - ",""),"Employees")</Value>
    <Width>289.1614mm</Width>
    <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
  </Textbox>
```

Here is my attempt -> the compiler doesn;t compain, but it doesn't set the value of the xml doc..When debugging, the compiler complains that the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.":

```
 var thisIsTheNode = (from data in rep.ReportDefinitionDoc.Descendants(ns + "Textbox")
                      where data.Attribute("Name").Value == "pageHeaderReportTitle"
                      select data.Element("Width")).FirstOrDefault();

 thisIsTheNode.SetValue("500mm");
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to update a "TextAlign" only when the parent is "Textbox"?

Comment: Yeah..I'm interested in retrieval and modification of that particular element....

Comment: Shouldn't "TextBox" be "Textbox"?

Comment: Yes it should! But this is not the problem...I still get the same error

Comment: Then the problem is with your namespace, make sure you are using the correct namespace or better try removing it. use Descendants("Textbox")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from the XML it seems `<Textbox>` and `<Width>` are in the same namespace and you're explicitly specifying the namespace for `<Textbox>`, but not for `<Width>`, I think that's the problem and you should change your `select` to:

```
select data.Element(ns + "Width")
```

Also, you shouldn't use `FirstOrDefault()` and then use the result without checking for `null`. Either add that check, if you expect that the sequence may be empty, or use `First()`.